# identifying the proper syntax for using HTTP dataset in ADFv2

Tags: postman, api-design, azure-data-factory

I am able to successfully use Postman to authenticate and subsequently get data housed within a sandbox but I cannot figure out how to specify the same data within ADFv2.

I'm expecting to retrieve, temporarily store and later use a bearer token that this API generates.  This token is then used in the second step that actually downloads the data I want in JSON format.

For the Authentication step, Postman generates code that looks this:

```
POST /v1/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sandbox.COMPANY.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: MYKEY
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundaryALPHANUM
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: MYTOKEN

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

MYKEY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

vapi_key
------WebKitFormBoundaryALPHANUM--
```

I've created a linked HTTP and REST connection in ADFv2 with the base URL of "https://api.sandbox.COMPANY.com" and using no authentication.

I cannot figure out how to translate the functional Postman connection to a way that ADFv2 will work.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could check this example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http#dataset-properties

Comment: thanks, it turns out I was using an incorrect setting in Postman to get the above code, which was leading me astray